# element.style or window.getComputedStyle() does not showing float

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to copy all element style properties, to another element. (both inline and inheritance)
to do so I am using window.getComputedStyle(), but when I am taking all the style values the `float` value does not exist.
I even tried to use element.style and it not exist there.

but when I am using jQuery.css('float') I am getting the right value back, so it's exists for sure!

do you have any solution or smart way to do it?

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/Xs45R/ Can you post some code that will reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 9):

Two things to consider: `window.getComputedStyle()` does not work in IE < 9 (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle)). Also, when accessing the float value via `element.style`, the property is named `cssFloat` because 'float' is a reserved word in JS (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)). In IE < 9, the property is named `styleFloat`.

The reason your example works via jQuery is because jQuery knows of the inherent browser differences when reading calculated styles, and smoothes over them so that you can access them via a consistent API.

`element.style` maps to the style attribute, which does not consider inherited/external styles. For old IE, the property you want is `element.currentStyle`, which takes the inherited styles into account.

If you need a solution that does not rely on jQuery, you'll need to check for `window.getComputedStyle()` and use it if present, and fall-back to `element.currentStyle` for old IE (using the property `styleFloat`).

Hope that helps, cheers!