# How to access CSS style of a DOM element with pure DOM functions (without jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

For some reason I can't access HTML element's `display` style's value.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#warning');
console.log(el.style.display)
```

My code returns `""` empty string for `#warning`'s `display`style but it's actually `"none"`.

I've the following HTML:

```
<div id="warning">
 warning warning warning.
</div>
```

I've the following CSS:

```
#warning {
    display: none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `#warning` would be for jQuery. Try using `warning` without the #?

Comment: This is not correct information. # is for ids regardless of jquery

Comment: you can use `clientWith` or `clientHeight`. if they are `0` it may be `display: none` (It is not optimistic way, but way)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything right for the most part, but what you are running into is a hangup for most people when they try this for the first time.

The style object in javascript is looking for this value to be inside the actual element (inline) and does not look for it in css code directly.

To access the style, the style has to exist in the dom. You could look into [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

I hope this explains why you are reaching this roadblock.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the element is an ID I'd suggest you use the `getElementById();` function. Also **AFAIK** the style method gets inline styles only. I'd suggest using `getComputedStyle();`.

**Code**

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

alert(getComputedStyle(myDiv).display);
```

Will output "none".

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/43jLLd5L/

**Reading Material**

[Not directly related to your question but the answer has some good points.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547672/element-style-or-window-getcomputedstyle-does-not-showing-float)